# Figuring out a range with given values

Tags: elementary-number-theory

firstly my math is terrible :( I need to figure out a formulae for an app I am making

I need to figure out the spacing between objects

Firstly I will have minimum pages of 3 to a max 20

If I have min pages the spacing value must be 8. If I have maximum pages the spacing value would be 1.

How do I work out the spacing value for the pages in between given a page number

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want the spacing value to change linearly with the page number, the problem reduces to finding the equation of a line through the points $(3, 8)$ and $(20, 1)$. The first co-ordinate represents the page number $x$, and the second co-ordinate represents the spacing value $y$.

The general formula for a line through $(x_{1}, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ is given by:

$y = y_1 + \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1} (x - x_1) \tag{1}$

Substituting $(x_1, y_1) = (3, 8)$ and $(x_2, y_2) = (20, 1)$, we get:

$y = 8 + \frac{1 - 8}{20 - 3}\left(x - 3 \right) \tag{2}$

On simplification, you get the desired formula:
$\boxed{y = \frac{1}{17}\left(157 - 7x\right)} \tag{3}$

I've also [plotted](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/h20m4cpwbz) it for visualization.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I needed.